# I have a 32 bit application tha needs to write to the 64bit registry when installed with installshield

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, installshield

I have a setup project (installshiedl) where i need to write a value in the registry which internet explorer reads to force its emulator mode to be that of version 8.0.
But when i run this on a 64-bit os it is written under wow6432node which is not acceptable since internet explorer is not targeting this part of the registry. How do i force installshield to target the 64 bit registry while my application is 32 bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifies that all future general registry operations affect the 64-bit parts of the registry instead of the 32-bit parts of the registry (on a 64-bit system).

REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS | REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;

RegDBSetKeyValueEx ( szKey, szName, nType, szValue, nSize );

REGDB_OPTIONS = REGDB_OPTIONS & ~REGDB_OPTION_WOW64_64KEY;

Comment: Well it seems that this is the solution But I have the version that comes together with visual studio. And it does not support Installscript. Do you know anyohter way? 
Thank you very much